# MongoDB Converting Circular Structure to JSON error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query a collection of users using Mongoose in a Node API.

The handler looks like this:

```
exports.getUsers = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let users = db.User.find();
        return res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch(e) {
        return next(e);
    }
};
```

This returns an error that reads `Converting circular structure to JSON`. When I console.log() the results of db.User.find(), I get a Query object. I've checked everything else. All of my other routes are working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I figured it out. I'll post the answer that I discovered in case anyone else is trying to figure this out. It turns out, through a little bit more careful reading of the documentation, that the Query object that is returned has to be executed. There are two ways to execute it - with a callback function or by returning a promise (but not both). I found [this page on queries in the mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) helpful. My final handler looked like this.

```
exports.getUsers = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        db.User.find()
            .then(users => {
                return res.status(200).json(users);
            });
    } catch(e) {
        return next(e);
    }
};
```

Next time I guess I'll dig around for a few more minutes before asking.

Edit to add:

Found a second solution. Due to the use of the async function, I also was able to use following inside the try block.

```
let users = await db.User.find();
return res.status(200).json(users);
```